# How to capture a node in Vivaldi?

Tags: screenshot, vivaldi

I open the inspect panel in Vivaldi, right click on a node, but can't see where to screenshot it. This [official help](https://help.vivaldi.com/guide/key-features/take-a-screenshot/) doesn't mention anything about it.

Do you know how to do that?

## Vivaldi

[image]

## Firefox

[image]

Comment: no, I can use screenshot tools, but I want to do that via the inspect element panel

Comment: Can you add an image of what the Firefox node screenshot looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now works in Vivaldi:

[image: Vivaldi Screen Grab]

But:

1. Is buried in developer tools (F12 or right click / Developer tools / inspect)
2. Saves to "Downloads" folder by default despite whatever it says under "Settings / Webpages / Capture storage folder"

Answer (score 1):

"Capturing" a *node* as a screenshot doesn't really make sense - the node, in DOM terms, may not even be visible. If you're interested in the DOM element, you can use the Copy submenu shown in your screenshot (to get the outerHTML, or the selector - the inspector is the same as in Chrome).

It sounds more - correct me if I'm wrong - like you're trying to capture a specific *display area* of a webpage, which is what the help page you linked to is about, and it shows you several ways of doing that. Easiest way of trying it out:

1. Just use the camera icon at the bottom of the screen as described in the "From the Status Bar" section on that help page (although it looks a little different in my version).
2. Choose "Selection", and then the format (PNG or JPEG), or just "Copy to Clipboard" so you can paste it somewhere later.
3. The cursor changes to a crosshair; drag your mouse from one corner of the area you want to capture to the opposite one, click the capture icon on the bottom right.
4. The file is saved and an explorer window opens to the file's location (`c:\Users\[username]\My Pictures\Vivaldi Captures` by default), or the area screenshot is copied to the clipboard if that's what you selected.

This being Vivaldi, you can of course customise a keyboard shortcut to do that as well, in [vivaldi://settings/keyboard/](http://vivaldi://settings/keyboard/) under "Window", add your favourite shortcut to "Capture Area to File" or "Capture Area to Clipboard".

**Clarification based on comments and updated question:**

Chromium-based browsers currently do not have this Firefox functionality you're looking for. Since you tagged this question *Vivaldi*, the closest way of doing it is described above. You could, of course, always [request a feature](https://help.vivaldi.com/article/request-a-new-feature-in-vivaldi/) from Vivaldi, or wait until a similar feature is added to the Chromium inspector.

Comment: so is it true that there is no way to screenshot a node in Vivaldi? Firefox can do that.

Comment: @Ooker: Sorry, not that I'm aware of - and it would be available in any Chromium-based browser.

Comment: just to make it clear, do you mean that any Chromium-based browser can screenshot a node in inspect element, but Vivaldi can't?

Comment: @Ooker: I meant if any [Chromium-based browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Other_browsers_based_on_Chromium) had that feature, all of them would (depending on version, of course), as the inspector is part of Chromium. So this isn't a Vivaldi thing, it's Chrome/Opera/Brave/Epic/etc. (and soon Edge, urgh).

Comment: I see. This is what I'm looking for. If you can add this to your answer, I'll accept it